# 英語が残っている: 編集履歴: Post Made Community Wiki

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URL例: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/11/revisions#spacer-bb0f2af3-6710-4732-aae4-7dbb90bc9938

[image: Post Made Community Wiki]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

適当翻訳：

$user$がポストをコミュニティ wikiに変換された